# Summed file size not matching filesystem report in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to sum of all files in a directory and get their total size in Ruby using `File.stat().size`. You can see below when I do this, the result is much much smaller than the result of `du -h` any ideas on how to make a better file size summation or what might be causing the discrepancy?

```
~ $ du -h tmp/cache/assets
89M tmp/cache/assets
~ $ irb
irb(main):001:0> dir  = "tmp/cache/assets"
=> "tmp/cache/assets"
irb(main):002:0> size = Dir.glob("#{ dir }/**/*").inject(0) {|sum, asset| sum += File.stat(asset).size ; sum }
=> 49904065
irb(main):003:0>
irb(main):004:0* puts "Bytes: #{ size }"
Bytes: 49904065
=> nil
irb(main):005:0> puts "Mb: #{ size / 1_048_576.0 }"
Mb: 47.592225074768066
```

Notice that 47mb as reported by Ruby is quite a bit smaller than 89 mb reported by `du`. How do I get the same result as `du -h` from Ruby?

Comment: At the very least you'd need to run equivalent commands; `glob` won't do anything with `.` directories/files. `du` may also use block size (or whatever) in its calculations, e.g., no directory total will be under 4K on my system whereas `stat` will count bytes.

Comment: Suggestions on an "equivalent" command?

Comment: Include dot directories and files first and see what the delta is. You'll have to do something to account for block size. It's not clear which number you actually *want*: actual size (`stat`) or blocks (`du`).

Comment: This may help: http://superuser.com/questions/94217/ls-and-du-shows-very-different-size

Comment: @DaveNewton Dir.glob("#{ dir }/**/*",  File::FNM_DOTMATCH) shows the `.` directories but is way too high 156mb.

Comment: @georgebrock thanks, didn't know about sparse files when i run `du -hs tmp/cache/assets/ --apparent-size` i'm getting 48mb which is pretty close to my calculated size in Ruby. All of this helps, however i've got more questions than I started with. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: @Schneems You'd also need to check for sym links etc. Bottom line is that unless you get a list of the files being considered you'll never know why the differences exist. Capture the file names and compare.